# transposing and collating text from different sheets into separate sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using the following formula to collate text from 3 sheets into a 4th.

```
=$'sheet 1'.A1&CHAR(10)&$'sheet 2'.A1&CHAR(10)&$'sheet 3'.A1&CHAR(10)
```

this collates the text with a return after each sheets contribution. However the return remains even it the is no text in the corresponding box e.g. sheet 1 has 'hi' sheet 2 empty, sheet 3 there looks like:

```
hi

there.
```

leaving a return between the 'hi' and the 'there' where any text from sheet 2 would be. I want the return only to be used if there is text from the corresponding cell so there is no return space between.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="","",Sheet1!A1 & CHAR(10)) & IF(Sheet2!A1="","",Sheet2!A1 & CHAR(10)) & IF(Sheet3!A1="","",Sheet3!A1 )
```